# Spring Roo and reports specialy BIRT

Tags: report, spring-roo, birt

I have gone through Spring Roo documentation and gvNIX as well. I found that they support reports as well. How can I generate code to create the report (Jasper or BIRT).

I want to integrate BIRT report with Spring Roo aplication. I am very keen to integrate BIRT report with different filter criteria.

If some gives me sample code or tutorial link it will help me a lot.

Comment: I wonder if there is something for BIRT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gvNIX provides auto generated code for Jasper out of the box. Please follow the manual and i believe it should work. Please share your steps and the error you are facing.

Comment: Can you give me specific link.